# Javascript: How to load data from specific parts of a text file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say I have a text file named test.txt with the following contents:

```
Apples.Purchased: 100
Oranges.Purchased: 202
Bananas.Purchased: 140
```

How can I search the text file for 'Oranges.Purchased', grab the numerical value behind it and apply it to a javascript variable?

For the record, I am using fs.write to save data:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile("test.txt", outputdata, function(err) {
        if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("The file was saved!");
        }
});
```

Comment: If you are writing the file yourself, why not use JSON to start with?  Might make search unnecessary.

Comment: I've not worked with Node.js, so i don't know if there is a plug-in for reading text, but from a Javascript point of view, you can use Regular Expressions to read specific parts of a string. http://lawrence.ecorp.net/inet/samples/regexp-intro.php

Comment: Totally agree with Lucas. You really should consider **JSON**. Will make reading (and writing) way easier. Once you've parsed the JSON file contents into a JS object, reading can be as easy as `object['Oranges']['Purchased']` (depending on how you write it out ofcourse)

Comment: @Erik can you assept some answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the file in as text and then use a regex to find your text:

```
fs.readFile("test.txt", function(err, data){
  var regex = /^Oranges.Purchased: ([0-9]+)/;
  var result = regex.exec(data);
  console.log(result[1]);
});
```

Though you'll want to bulletproof that (check the err, don't just assume you found the text, etc).

But I don't recommend that approach in general. Why not write the file as JSON:

```
{
  "Apples": {
    "Purchased": 100
  },
  "Oranges": {
    "Purchased": 140
  }
  "Bananas": {
    "Purchased": 202
  }
}
```

Which can be generated and parsed without any string wrangling; you can just serialize your objects.

Comment: You don't need the `new` before the regex literal.

Comment: Technically, the example isn't valid JSON, since JSON requires properties to be quoted. But a JSON library would take care of that.

Comment: Use `new Regex(...)` or simply `/.../`

Comment: ah, thanks, fixed. Yeah, I was switching from `new RegExp()` to the literal syntax and ended up writing something in between. I also changed the JSON syntax.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Converted to JSON. I can already tell it's going to make everything much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing into JSON is the ideal solution here.

However, let me play devils advocate and provide the non-json solution, which just scans the file line-by-line, compares the keyword with the target value.  If they match, then we assign the value to a variable.

Of course, this assumes that the data format is strictly as you've shown here.  That is, for every line, there is a (Keyword:Value) pair.  If not, this will probably raise.

```
target = 'Oranges.Purchased'
value_to_save = None
file = open('/tmp/contents.txt', 'r')

for i in file.readlines():
    value_pair = i.split(':')
    if value_pair[0].strip('') == target:
        value_to_save = value_pair[1].strip('')
        break

print value_to_save
```